# Content restiction based on product expiration

Tags: cartthrob

I'm building a portfolio site, on which user profiles shall become invisible after a custom period of time. So users can purchase e.g. a month of public display.

Is this possible using CartThrob? Maybe having the user purchase a product with an expiration date or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, including an expiration_date parameter in the add_to_cart_form is exactly how you would do it. The expiration date is entered as days from purchase. `{exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form expiration_date="30"}`

Set the channel that holds your public profiles as your purchased items channel in the CartThrob > Orders settings tab. Then the entries that get added there will have expiration dates.